# PHP(Laravel) storing class object

Tags: php, json, laravel, guzzle

I'm receiving JSON data from API using guzzle package. The received data I want to store in a Database:

[JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jytTA.jpg)

My data saving to database code:

```
$contents = json_decode($response->getBody());

$object = new Product();

$object->GeneralInfo = $contents->data->GeneralInfo;
    $object->save();


    return response()->json($contents);
```

Exception I'm receiving: **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

I understand it wants to store string and object being passed. What would be the best way to store this data? Convert to array maybe? Thanks for the tips in advance.

Comment: Could you try adding this to your json_decode line `$contents = json_decode($response->getBody(), true)`

Comment: Tried that, it sets response to array, right? Then I get 'Trying to get property 'data' of non-object' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General info from contents is object. When laravel tries to insert it to your database it tries to casts array to string. So when it gets and object it can't convert it to string.

decode your response body to array:
`$contents = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);`

then get your data from array:
`$object->GeneralInfo = $contents['data']['GeneralInfo'];`

Comment: Getting Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given. I find this odd since response has been set to array.

Comment: dump what you are getting from `$contents['data']['GeneralInfo']`

Comment: Array as expected

Comment: Have you setted $cast in your model for column 'GeneralInfo' ? `protected $casts = ['GeneralInfo' => 'array'];`

Comment: I have not before, but it did help, thank you a lot, sir.